# Disable vim angle bracket highlighting in HAML template

Tags: php, vim, haml

I'm using PHP in some HAML templates, so I've got a lot of `<?php echo ...?>` going on. Vim is highlighting all the greater-than signs with the ErrorMsg highlighting group, but it gets quite annoying, as you can see:

[image: Bad syntax highlighting]

What's the best way to disable this for HAML templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, you could forcibly remove the highlighting for angle brackets with these commands:

```
:syn match Normal '<'
:syn match Normal '>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [syntax highlighting](http://beerpla.net/2008/04/02/how-to-add-a-vim-file-extension-to-syntax-highlighting/) for specific file types in vim.  So for .haml files put something in your `.vimrc` like:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.haml set filetype=haml
```

then make a haml.vim file in your home/.vim/ folder.

Also check out this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/113455/vim-highlighting-for-specific-file-types-where-to-put-syntax-files-vim-events)

Comment: MacVim ships with a haml syntax file by default. I can't decipher it well enough to determine which part is causing the error highlighting, but suppose I just wanted to remove highlighting for > angle brackets. Any idea how I might do that?

Comment: mmm sorry I'm linux based, but like you suggested, you could remove highlighting for > brackets or just guess and check removing stuff from the file until the error goes away.  Sorry I can't be of more help.